# Issue with Follow/Unfollow buttons

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this program below that does a simple follow/unfollow function.  Everything works great except that when I refresh the page only the first user in the row retains the correct follow/unfollow button.  Example I can follow user1 user2 and user3 but when I refresh only user1 still says FOllOWING.  Not sure what the issue is, maybe someone can spot a flaw in the code.  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.livequery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
           $(document).ready(function() { 

                    $('.buttons > a').livequery("click",function(e){

                        var parent  = $(this).parent();
                        var getID   =  parent.attr('id').replace('button_','');

                        $.post("follow.php?id="+getID, {

                        }, function(response){

                            $('#button_'+getID).html($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
                        });
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body> 

    <br clear="all" />

        <div id="content"> 

        <br clear="all" />
        <br clear="all" />
        <?php  



        $test = $fgmembersite-> UserID();

            $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT fgusers.*, tblimage.* FROM fgusers LEFT JOIN tblimage ON tblimage.userid = fgusers.id_user");

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {?>
                <div class="digg-panel">

                    <div class="img-username">

                        <img alt="<?php  echo $row['username']?>" src="<?php  echo $row['photo']?>.png" width="40" height="40" class="userImage" alt="" />
                        <div class="user-title">
                            <a href="http://digg.com/<?php  echo $row['username']?>" class="fullname"><?php  echo $row['name']?></a>

                            <a href="http://digg.com/<?php  echo $row['username']?>" class="username"><?php  echo $row['username']?></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                    $res = mysql_query("select * from tblfollowers where follower_id = '$test' AND username = ".$row['id']);

                    $check_result = @mysql_num_rows(@$res);

                    if($check_result > 0)
                    {?>
                        <span class="buttons" id="button_<?php echo $row['id_user']?>"><a class="btn-following" href="javascript: void(0)"></a></span>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {?>
                        <span class="buttons" id="button_<?php echo $row['id_user']?>"><a class="btn-follow" href="javascript:void(0)"></a></span>
                        <?php
                    }?>
                    <br clear="all" />

                    <div class="bio">
                    <?php  echo $row['email']?>
                    </div>

                </div>
            <?php  
            }?>






        </div> 


        <br clear="all" />

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You indicated how you we have unexpected behavior, but you made no mention as to whether you are getting any actual errors (i.e. javscript errors, PHP errors, MySQL errors). Are you looking in your javascript console for errors?  Do you have PHP error reporting turned on? Have you considered using performing MySQL error handling and seeing any DB errors you might be getting by using `mysql_error()`? Have you tried to `var_dump()` certain variables at key point in your code to verify the values you are getting are what you are expecting?  These steps you should take on your own.

Comment: @mike brant yes I've done all that. There are not MySQL errors or php errors. The values are being pulled in correctly. I've done a lot of work putting it together and I got stuck at this point because I can't see why the first row would recognize the action and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement your `click event` like below.May be your problem will solve.Try it.

```
$('.buttons > a').expire("click").livequery("click",function(e){

});
```

For more information check [**jQuery Live Query Plugin Documentation**](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: sorry I tried that but doesn't work. When I refresh the page still shows the wrong button. Thanks for the suggestion